# Bundler looking for old version of gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

Im using earnshark_sdk 0.2.0 ruby gem in my app, and now i would like to use the latest version 0.2.1. So i tried doing the following

Gemfile:

```
gem 'earnshark_sdk', '~> 0.2.1'
```

I did a `bundler update`

Since the app is dockerized, i tried going inside the container and removing the old version and installed the new one.

`gem list` shows `earnshark_sdk (0.2.1)`

When i `docker-compose up` it gives

[image]

I'm new to both ruby and docker, any suggestion would be welcomed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question,

My docker container was not able to detect my gemfile, by defining a default path for the the gemfile in the compose I was able to fix this.

Added a volume mount in docker-compose.yml

```
volumes:
    - /e/Workspaces/MyApp/src/Gemfile:/home/app/webapp/Gemfile
```

Answer (score 2):

You see it because in your system you have one version of a gem but in docker container another.
So you need run `bundle install` inside docker container.
To do this you need wrote:
   `docker exec -it <your container name/id> <command which you want to run>`

In your case:
`docker exec <container name\id> gem list` - to check gems inside container
`docker exec <container name\id> bundle install` - to install gems inside container
You can read about it  [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/)

Comment: To find container name/id you need run `docker ps`

Comment: Did you mean `bundle install` in 2nd line here?

Comment: Yes, the gem list inside my docker container shows earnshark_sdk 0.2.1 as well. And i did a bundle install there as well.

Comment: Yes @dendomenko

Comment: Can you attach your docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile, please?

Comment: I was able to fix this by adding a volume mount for my gemfile. Thanks much for your help @dendomenko.